# Ruby - can't get JSON params into my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

I have the following code in my api/ProjectController:

```
class Api::ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Project.all
  end

  def show
    respond_with Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `project_params' for #<Api::ProjectsController:0x00003d6d80b448>
```

When I change the second line in the create method to:

```
@project = Project.new(params[:project])
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

I am using ember and am sending JSON representation of the Project object from the front end. In both instances this is the json that's being propagated to the controller:

```
{"project"=>{"name"=>"asdfsdfsdf"}}
```

Can someone please spot where the mistake is.. I feel like I'm spending more time on this than I really should.. :/

Thank you so much and happy new year!!

Comment: Need more info.post the model

Comment: undefined local variable or method `project_params'--method project_params is not defined in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the `project_params` method that you're trying to use:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name)
end
```

You'll find more information and example on Rails 4 [Strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have the `project_params` method defined in your Api::ProjectsController class. You need to add a method to your Api::ProjectsController called `project_params` like:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:attribute)
end
```

Just replace the :attribute symbol with the actual attributes for the corresponding fields in your form. So if you have a 'name' and 'start_date' field for your project, then your require will look like `params.require(:project).permit(:name, :start_date)`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is correct, however Baldrick answered it first. I upvoted your comment! Thank you!